# convergence of this unique series and calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

sigma n = 1 to inifinity of n/(n+1)

So, I get that the series converges to 1 but is that enough justification?

Comment: No. The *sequence* $\displaystyle{n\over n+1}$ converges to 1. If a sequence doesn't converge to 0, then the *series* will diverge.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sequences and series are two different things. A sequence is a list of numbers. A series is the sum of those numbers.

Comment: then how to show this diverges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One test that would be applicable here to test for convergence or divergence is the **n-th term test.** This test states that if the limit as $n$ approaches infinity of the **sequence** (in terms of $n$) is not $0,$ the **series** diverges (hopefully this makes some intuitive sense).

We have the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n + 1}$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}$$
$$= 1.$$

Since the limit is $1,$ although the **sequence** converges, the **series** diverges.